# Rspec & Rails create action testing Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

Hey guys I'm trying to test this create method in controller spec :

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I tried this but the user model doesn't seem to increment, in addition I would like to test mailer account activation as well:

```
  it "creates a new user" do
    expect{
      post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
    }.to change(User,:count).by(1)
  end
```

Comment: maybe `@user.save` not success

Comment: I would suggest to remove FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user) and pass your own attributes. User model might be verifying associations that are not set with 'FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)'

Otherwise, it would be helpful to see the code on User model.

Comment: In your create, it looks like you might have a before_filter to clean the params, user_params. In your test, you're posting FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user). Is it possible the attributes aren't matching up with the filter? You can always test with raw params. Or you can always use unit tests for the User creation and Mail delivery.